# UIButton title inside UITableViewCell changes on reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, swift4

I have a table view which has a data that consists of both phone contacts and facebook friends. the cell's button title should be "Invite" if the user is a contact and "Add" if it is a facebook friend.

However, the titles on each button are wrong and are swapping on scroll.

here is my model:

```
struct MyContact {
   var name: String
   var phone: String
   var photoUrl: String
   var isFBUser: Bool
}
```

model array

```
var myContacts = [MyContact]()
```

cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexpath: Indexpath)  -> UITableviewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell

   let contact = myContacts[indexPath.row]

   if contact.isFBUser == true {
      cell.button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
   } else {
      cell.button.setTitle("Invite", for: .normal)
   }

   cell.contact = contact
   cell.configureCell()
}
```

ContactCell.swift

```
func configureCell() {
   if contact.isFBUser == true {
      button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
   } else {
      button.setTitle("Invite", for: .normal)
   }
}
```

I even tried setting the button title to nil on prepareForReuse

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
  super.prepareForReuse      

   button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, but could you show `CellForRowAtIndex` to be sure? Do you set the `contact` on the cell before calling `configureCell()`? Also, how is created the button?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: if you are passing a contact object and you are calling `configureCell() ` then you don't need to make the `if contact.isFBUser == true {
      button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
   } else {
      button.setTitle("Invite", for: .normal)
   }`

Comment: The dequeueCell code? There is no "myCell.contact = someArray[indexpath.row]"? Your method doesn't return the cell?

Comment: I've updated my code again, sorry.

Comment: What is `contact` in `tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt:)`? Where is it defined? Where do you pass the `contact` from your tableView (controller?) to the cell?

Comment: Updated my code.

Comment: Your code seems right, even if the `if contact.isFBUser == true {` in the cellForRowAtIndexPath seems unnecessary., and the method isn't even returning the cell. When does occurs exactly your issue? Is it on each scroll, or once you taped on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell objects are reused so you need to keep setting the contact property of them when you dequeue them (or pass it to `configureCell()`)

Comment: Can you give me an example if you don't mind? I'm quite confused since I thought my code in cellForRowAt is already doing it? The setting of property all the time.